# Adding Hostname to servers hosts file still doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, hostname, hosts-file

On server: I go to start -> run and type "drivers" change to the etc directory you want to edit the hosts file.My website was seen when i go from iis(from the server) Right click websitename>Manage website>Browse.

On local computer: (This computer can access the server)I open browser>type the hostname on url , i can't view the website. How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following:

1. Under IIS (inetmgr), is application binded with any IP?
2. If answer to #1 is YES, use that IP in your host file. If NO, you can
   either use user machine IP or localhost (i.e. 127.0.0.1).

Thank you

Comment: Under my Edit bindings was i set ip address to -all unassigned and port to 8080 (because port 80 is already used). I tried adding the ip add of the server in hosts file, but still it doesn't show up.

Comment: I have already deployed it to server, I changed the port number and it worked in Chrome, but not in IE 11. I can't view the website